# How to remove special characters except space from a file in python?

Tags: python, regex, string, file, string-formatting

I have a huge corpus of text (line by line) and I want to remove special characters but sustain the space and structure of the string.

```
hello? there A-Z-R_T(,**), world, welcome to python.
this **should? the next line#followed- by@ an#other %million^ %%like $this.
```

should be

```
hello there A Z R T world welcome to python
this should be the next line followed by another million like this
```

Comment: Just create a list of the characters you want, A-Z, a-z, 0-9, etc.. And use a `for` loop for iterate over each character in the string replacing the characters thats not in the list with a space.

Comment: is that efficient for a huge corpus of million of lines of text?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

You can use this pattern, too, with `regex`:

```
import re
a = '''hello? there A-Z-R_T(,**), world, welcome to python.
this **should? the next line#followed- by@ an#other %million^ %%like $this.'''

for k in a.split("\n"):
    print(re.sub(r"[^a-zA-Z0-9]+", ' ', k))
    # Or:
    # final = " ".join(re.findall(r"[a-zA-Z0-9]+", k))
    # print(final)
```

Output:

```
hello there A Z R T world welcome to python 
this should the next line followed by an other million like this
```

Edit:

Otherwise, you can store the final lines into a `list`:

```
final = [re.sub(r"[^a-zA-Z0-9]+", ' ', k) for k in a.split("\n")]
print(final)
```

Output:

```
['hello there A Z R T world welcome to python ', 'this should the next line followed by an other million like this ']
```

Comment: this does the job but how to prevent it from putting together all the rows into one single very long row?

Answer (score 9):

I think nfn neil answer is great...but i would just add a simple regex to remove all no words character,however it will consider underscore as part of the word

```
print  re.sub(r'\W+', ' ', string)
>>> hello there A Z R_T world welcome to python
```

Answer (score 6):

you can try this

```
import re
sentance = '''hello? there A-Z-R_T(,**), world, welcome to python. this **should? the next line#followed- by@ an#other %million^ %%like $this.'''
res = re.sub('[!,*)@#%(&$_?.^]', '', sentance)
print(res)
```

re.sub('["]') -> here you can add which symbol you want to remove

Answer (score 4):

A more elegant solution would be

`print(re.sub(r"\W+|_", " ", string))`

`>>> hello there A Z R T world welcome to python this should the next line followed by another million like this`

Here, 
`re` is `regex` module in python

`re.sub` will substitute pattern with space i.e., `" "`

`r''` will treat input string as raw `(with \n)`

`\W` for all non-words i.e. all special characters *&^%$ etc excluding underscore _

`+` will match zero to unlimited matches, similar to * (one to more)

`|` is logical OR

`_` stands for underscore

Answer (score 0):

Create a dictionary mapping special characters to None

```
d = {c:None for c in special_characters}
```

Make a [translation table](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.maketrans) using the dictionary.  Read the entire text into a variable and use [str.translate](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.translate) on the entire text.