# How to delete words that do not match exactly the black list due to additional characters in the word?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, substring

I am making a Discord bot that blocks swear words. It can be bypassed by using underscores and/or other symbols attached to the swear word.

How do I get the script to still block these words but not delete characters in general?

Here is my code:

```
import discord
import random
import string
from discord.ext import commands

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix = 'as-')

with open("badwords2.txt") as file:
    bad_words = file.read().splitlines()

def check_if_allowed(text):

    allowed_characters = string.ascii_uppercase + string.ascii_lowercase 
    
    if character not in allowed_characters: 
        return False

    return True
    
@client.event
async def on_message(message):    
    for bad_word in bad_words:
        if bad_word in message.content.lower().split(" "):
            t = discord.Embed(color=0x039e00, title="Message Removed", description=":x:   Please do not swear. Swearing can result in a mute or ban.")
            t.set_footer(text="DM TheSuperRobert2498#2498 for bot suggestions.")
            await message.channel.send(embed=t)
            await message.delete()
            return

    if not check_if_allowed(message.content):
        t = discord.Embed(color=0x039e00, title="Message Removed", description=":x:  Please do not swear. Swearing can result in a mute or ban.")
        t.set_footer(text="DM TheSuperRobert2498#2498 for bot suggestions.")
        await message.channel.send(embed=t)
        await message.delete()
        return


client.run('TOKEN')
```

Answer (score 0):

If my message is **"hey guys @#@@_badWord@@ what's up?"** then, `message.content.lower().split(" ")` is `["hey", "guys", "@#@@_badWord@@", "what's", "up?"]`

So you can be creative with this list that you are checking.

Maybe do

```
[re.sub(r'\W+', ' ', word) for word in content.message.content.lower().split(" ")]
```

which will create a new list (using list comprehension) that has each word with the special characters removed (using RegEx substitution)

See: [How to remove special characters except space from a file in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43358857/how-to-remove-special-characters-except-space-from-a-file-in-python)

I also recommend making this into a function so you don't have to write the code twice:

```
t = discord.Embed(color=0x039e00, title="Message Removed", description=":x:   Please do not swear. Swearing can result in a mute or ban.")
t.set_footer(text="DM TheSuperRobert2498#2498 for bot suggestions.")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try and remove all special character from the words with the `re.sub()` function from the `re` module:

```
    clearMessage = re.sub('[^A-Za-z0-9]+', '', message.content))
```

And remove the spaces:

```
    clearMessage = clearMessage.replace(" ","")
```

If you put it in your code it would look something like this:

```
import random
import string
import re
from discord.ext import commands

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix = 'as-')

with open("badwords2.txt") as file:
    bad_words = file.read().splitlines()

def check_if_allowed(text):

    allowed_characters = string.ascii_uppercase + string.ascii_lowercase #creates a string containing all upper- and lower- case letters.

    if character not in allowed_characters: #checks if the character is in the set of allowed characters, and returns false if not
        return False

    return True #returns true if every character in the input is allowed
    
@client.event
async def on_message(message):    
    clearMessage = re.sub('[^A-Za-z0-9]+', '', message.content))
    clearMessage = clearMessage.replace(" ","")

    for bad_word in bad_words:
        if bad_word in clearMessage:
            t = discord.Embed(color=0x039e00, title="Message Removed", description=":x:   Please do not swear. Swearing can result in a mute or ban.")
            t.set_footer(text="DM TheSuperRobert2498#2498 for bot suggestions.")
            await message.channel.send(embed=t)
            await message.delete()
            return

    if not check_if_allowed(message.content):
        t = discord.Embed(color=0x039e00, title="Message Removed", description=":x:  Please do not swear. Swearing can result in a mute or ban.")
        t.set_footer(text="DM TheSuperRobert2498#2498 for bot suggestions.")
        await message.channel.send(embed=t)
        await message.delete()
        return
```

You don't necessarily need to split your message into all words. The `if something in something` statement can also search raw strings

Comment: it works, but if there is an uppercase letter in the message it does not block it. Is there something wrong with the code? I looked over it, but from what I saw there wasn't anything wrong with it.

Comment: then please replace `clearMessage = re.sub('[^A-Za-z0-9]+', '', message.content))` with `clearMessage = re.sub('[^A-Za-z0-9]+', '', message.content)).lower()`.